# How do I have different pages share HTML code in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am rewriting a jQuery application to AngularJS. I have been using jQuery.Tmpl a lot, and have several templates shared across multiple pages, but with different databindings.

How would I in AngularJS have a repeater shared on multiple pages, but where the datasource is different?

Edit: The data objects have the same signature, and the paging is the same. So the objects doesn't vary except their content.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, but not a bad one. How different is your data: different paging, query parameters, or a completely different type of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-include with the template url. As long as the data is bound using the same type of object.